# How to go back to previous item in AWS Amplify CLI auth configuration?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I was wondering if there was a way to go back and edit the previous field while performing auth configuration via AWS Amplify in the command line terminal. By default, ***enter*** is to go forward, ***space*** is to select among several options, and ***a*** is to toggle all, but how does one go back to editing the previous field?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such option (go back to previous choice) in AWS Amplify CLI for now. Discussion is open here: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/6367

You might try to use "update" command, for example "amplify update auth", and change option which you would like to edit, but you have to complete configuration process before using the "update".